# Multi-threaded debugging tutorial for GDB and C

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, gdb

Does anybody know of a good GDB (or other Linux debugger) tutorial for debugging multi-threaded C code? I'm looking for one that includes simple examples.

Answer (score 16):

Googled it.Found some links.They seem helpful :

- redhat.com -[Debugging programs with multiple threads](https://web.archive.org/web/20120707203242/http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Debugging_with_gdb/threads.html)
- [Multi-threaded Debugging Techniques](http://www.ddj.com/199200938?pgno=6)

Answer (score 5):

When debugging multi-threaded C code using GDB, I usually refer to the entry in the gdb manual on "Debugging Programs with Multiple Threads". You can find it [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html).

It's not really a tutorial, but it does have a couple of examples that should get you started.

Answer (score 5):

In supplement to the various gdb tutorials out there I would really advise using "watch" alot in multi-threaded debugging. It will break on read/writes to memory/variables rather than specific lines of source.

Answer (score 2):

Above links broken, So, you can use the following link:[Debugging Programs with Multiple Threads](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html)