# What are some common ways to debug segmentation faults in multi-threaded c++ applications?

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

I am new to threads and have put together a basic command line application using pthread's.  I use  pthread_create passing a struct as the final param; starting a new thread which calls "void *thread_routine (void *arg)".  I have made a few observations worth noting. 
     - The program doesn't always provide the same results 
     - about 10% of the time the program seg faults

What are some good techniques to use when debugging multi-threaded applications in c++?

Comment: I think you would get more extended answers on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: The same ways as you would debug any other segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Watch for your shared memmory access and use logging to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

Segfault is only the visible part of the iceberg. It might be a result of race conditions, and in this case you should focus on ensuring that threads are properly synchronized. Then the remaining segfault should be different than the ones of a single-threaded application.

Answer (score 0):

You can apposite debugging support tools such as GDB which work fine also for multi-threaded programs.
Check out these links:

- http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_25.html
- [Multi-threaded debugging tutorial for GDB and C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695268/multi-threaded-debugging-tutorial-for-gdb-and-c)